# Does a sonic pulse in a gas enhance thermal mixing?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

I have a sonic pulse consisting of around 10 cycles that is propagated longitudinally through a gas in a tube. If there are thermal differentials in the gas (say between case and central portion of the tube) does the pulse enhance thermal mixing, inhibit it, or do nothing? In this specific situation wavelength is around 2mm and diameter of the tube is approx 25mm. Tubing length >> pulse length.

Comment: It is unlikely to have much of an effect: To a first (and rather good) approximation, sound waves simply move particles forth a bit without mixing them and only creating adiabatic heating and cooling. Anything beyond that, even just significant adiabatic heating or cooling, leave alone net transport/increased mixing, tends to require such extreme amplitudes you might argue that calling it a sound wave is misleading.

Comment: I don't know much about thermal mixing, but there is theory that presence of an acoustic field enhance vortex shedding in the fluid. So there could be something, but probably not as a "direct influence" (as pyramids pointed out). Generally, acoustics is very non-linear in boundary layers area. There are non-adiabatic processes.